# Unix filename wildcards in Python?

Tags: python, unix, pattern-matching, wildcard

How do Unix filename **wildcards** work from **Python**?

A given directory contains only subdirectories, in each of which there is (among others) one file whose name ends with a known string, say **`_ext`**. The first part of the filename always varies, so I need to get to the file by using this pattern.

I wanted to do this:

```
directory = "."
listofSubDirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)]
listofSubDirs = listofSubDirs[1:] #removing "."

for subDirectory in listofSubDirs:
    fileNameToPickle = subDirectory + "/*_ext" #only one such file exists
    fileToPickle = pickle.load(open(fileNameToPickle, "rb"))
    ... do stuff ...
```

But no pattern matching happens. How does it work under Python?

Comment: `glob.glob('*_ext')` supports wildcards.

Comment: You should indeed use glob: http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 10):

Shell wildcard patterns don't work in Python. Use the [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) or [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) modules to interpret the wildcards instead. `fnmatch` interprets wildcards and lets you match strings against them, `glob` uses `fnmatch` internally, together with `os.listdir()` to give you a list of matching filenames.

In this case, I'd use `fnmatch.filter()`:

```
import os
import fnmatch

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*_ext'):
        fileNameToPickle = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        fileToPickle = pickle.load(open(fileNameToPickle, "rb"))
```

If your structure contains only *one* level of subdirectories, you could also use a `glob()` pattern that expresses that; the `*/` in the *path* of expression is expanded to match all subdirectories:

```
import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*/*_ext')):
    # loops over matching filenames in all subdirectories of `directory`.
```