# how to write multiple csv files in python

Tags: python, csv

I need to convert excel to csv. But i can't multi write the csv file

```
import sys,os

sys.path.insert(0,'D:/apera/Python27/xlrd-0.9.3')

import xlrd
import csv

path = "D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding"

CSVFile1 = "D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding001.csv"
CSVFile2 = "D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding002.csv"


for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    xlsfiles=[ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xls') ]
    for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
        n = len(wb.sheets())
        ws = wb.sheet_by_name("INPUT")

        with open(CSVFile1, 'wb') as csvfile:
            wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=';')
            for rownum in xrange(ws.nrows):
                wr.writerow(list(x.encode('latin1')for x in ws.row_values(rownum)))

        with open(CSVFile2, 'wb') as csvfile:
            wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=';')
            for rownum in xrange(ws.nrows):
                wr.writerow(list(x.encode('latin1')for x in ws.row_values(rownum)))

        csvfile.close()
```

This the edited question. I need to write the csv files. This is only 2 files that needs to write. So I write it two times. So is there a way to make it simpler. So I don't need to with open csvfile3, 4, 5 and so on.. Thanks

Comment: use pandas... read in as `pandas.ExcelFile` object, and then use `DataFrame.to_csv()` function to write to csv. Much easier I'd say.

Comment: is it pandas a library?

Comment: Yes it is a python lubray

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about how to open multiple files using the "*" wildcard, then I think you could use the `glob` module (as you have already mentioned):

```
import glob


file_names = glob.glob("*.txt")

for file_name in file_names:
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')

    f.write("AAA")
```

And similar question regarding the filename wildcards in python was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949694/unix-filename-wildcards-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (for writing to multiple csv files):

```
import sys,os,xlrd,csv

sys.path.insert(0,'D:/apera/Python27/xlrd-0.9.3')

path = "D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding"

files_to_write = ["D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding1.csv","D:/apera/Workspace/Sounding/sounding2.csv"] 

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    xlsfiles=[ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xls') ]
    for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
        n = len(wb.sheets())
        ws = wb.sheet_by_name("INPUT")
        for z in files_to_write:    
            with open(z, 'wb') as csvfile:
                wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=';')
                for rownum in xrange(ws.nrows):
                    wr.writerow(list(x.encode('latin1')for x in ws.row_values(rownum)))
```

Comment: Indention with one space? That's unusual.

Comment: I don't mean to get all csv files. In my folder all of my files is in .xls. And i need to print all of them to csv files. So in the code have open(csvfile, 'wb'). It must open first then he can write it. So is there a way to multi open and write it?

Comment: Please check the edited answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: not only that. The most important is csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'wb')

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific as to what csv files do you want to write? Do you have a specific pattern? I tried to answer as per what I understood.

Comment: with open(CSVFile(n)) i don't know why all the csv file that want to be write must be open first. So that's why if I want to make multiple csv file. I must open multi csv file first then multi write it. Do u have a way? Thanks