# Wildcard in dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, wildcard, glob

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
rank_dict = {'V*': 1, 'A*': 2, 'V': 3,'A': 4}
```

As you can see, I have added a * to the end of one V. Whereas a 3 may be the value for just V, I want another key for V1, V2, V2234432, etc...I want to check it against:

```
checker = 'V30'
```

and get the value. what is the correct syntax for this?

```
for k, v in rank_dict.items():
    if checker == k:
        print(v)
```

Comment: '*' is simply a character. It's not a wildcard unless it's used by a command or function which treats it as a wildcard, such as `glob.glob()` or `fnmatch.fnmatch()`. But '==' on a string is merely the method `str.__eq__()`, which does not. And if you wanted to use `re.match/find...()` you'd need the wildcard to be `V.*`

Comment: There are many duplicates, such as [Unix filename wildcards in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949694/unix-filename-wildcards-in-python)

Comment: @smci, In the context of dictionaries, I think my solution is valid and not possible to put on the dup, I think it should be left open as (potentially) someone might come up with a better idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) to match Unix shell-style wildcards:

```
>>> import fnmatch
>>> fnmatch.fnmatch('V34', 'V*')
True
```

---

```
>>> rank_dict = {'V*': 1, 'A*': 2, 'V': 3,'A': 4}
>>> checker = 'V30'
>>> for k, v in rank_dict.items():
...     if fnmatch.fnmatch(checker, k):
...         print(v)
... 
1
```

NOTE: Every lookup will have O(n) time complexity. This may become an issue with large dictionaries. Recommended only if lookup performance is not an issue.

Comment: Wow, I like that! Super easy! Worked like a charm; thanks.

Comment: @jpp, Thank you for comment. I added your comment to answer as NOTE.

Answer (score 4):

I would split your single dictionary into two, a regular one and a wildcard-derived one, so you can maintain O(1) lookup time complexity.

```
rank_dict = {'V*': 1, 'A*': 2, 'V': 3,'A': 4}

d1 = {k: v for k, v in rank_dict.items() if not k.endswith('*')}
d2 = {k[0]: v for k, v in rank_dict.items() if k.endswith('*')}

def get_val(key, d1, d2):
    return d1.get(key, d2.get(key[0]))

get_val('V', d1, d2)    # 3
get_val('V30', d1, d2)  # 1
```