# Is there a faster method to find dictionary keys with wildcards in the middle?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance, dictionary, wildcard

Let's say I have a dictionary with strings of 0s, 1s, and '*' as wildcards for my key value.

For example, my dictionary is structured as such:

```
{'010*10000':'foo', '100*1*000':'bar'......}
```

Each dictionary value has a fixed string length, however, there are wildcards within the string represented as '*' characters. Thus, values of '010110000' or '010010000' both return 'foo'.

The problem lies in the length of my dictionary. The dictionary I am working with has over 500,000+ entries. Therefore, when I try to iterate over each key in the dict to find if a key exists, then it takes far too long with O(n) complexity.

Ideally, I would like to find a way to just check if a value such as '010110000' is in the dictionary, similar to the .get() function for regular python dictionaries without wildcards.

I've already tried iterating over my dictionary using fnmatch like the following [Wildcard in dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656701/wildcard-in-dictionary-key):

```
for k in my_dict.keys():
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(string_of_1s_and_0s, k):
        print(my_dict[k])
        break
##Do some operation here if we have found the matching key pair...and then break.
```

However, it's  just too slow with O(n) complexity. Is there any way to implement get() but with wildcards?

Comment: What's the actual length of the keys? I guess longer than the 9 digits from your example, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to get to 500K+ unique entries.

Comment: Are the strings "ones, zeros and wildcards" with nothing else? Specifically, can the characters before the first wildcard and the characters after the last wildcard be concatenated and then converted from "string containing binary digits" into a fixed size integer? If yes; you can quickly find all entries where the start and end match (using conversion from string to integer, a rotate count, and mask).

Comment: Is the wildcard just one character? How many wildcards? Could you just place the values into the dictionary twice (or more times) to cover every permutation and then use an exact match (normal dictionary lookup using hashes)?

Comment: The length of the keys is 90 long. Yes the strings are 1s, 0s, and nothing else. The wildcard is just 1 wildcard. I've considered putting every permutation. That was a possible step. Just wondering if there was a better way. Thanks for all your replies.

Answer (score 2):

`dict`s are hash code based; the hash code, if implemented correctly, will differ wildly for a difference of just one character. There is no way to make a `dict` do what you want, but what you're doing is probably best done with something other than a `dict` in the first place. Have you considered a relational database, where the `LIKE` operator could do something like this? It might still have to scan a large part of the DB, but ideally it could use anchors at one end or the other to at least narrow the search to matching prefixes/suffixes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've been thinking about restructuring the entire data structure. But I have no experience working SQL commands in python. Additionally, the dictionary key values are completely random.. there is no real way to tell how many wildcards exist and where they will be placed. I agree though, dictionaries might not be the best fit for this situation.

Comment: @Tianen: Yeah, in fact now that I reread your question, databases probably won't help much. You're trying to match a fixed string against a bunch of (arbitrarily complex) patterns. There just aren't any good ways to accomplish this that I'm aware of. Can you provide more details of your problem? I feel like there has to be a better solution that what you're trying.

Answer (score 2):

Rotate the original pattern left (by taking characters from the start and putting them at the end) while keeping track of the rotate count; like this:

```
'010*10000' -> '*10000010', rotate_count = 3
'100*1*000' -> '*1*000100', rotate_count = 3
```

Then split it into a "complex part" and a "simple part", and determine the length of the simple part, like this:

```
'010*10000' -> '*10000010', rotate_count = 3
               complex = '*`, simple = `10000010', simple_length = 8

'100*1*000' -> '*1*000100', rotate_count = 3
               complex = '*1*`, simple = `000100', simple_length = 6
```

If the fixed length of the strings is 16, then there will be 16 possible values of `rotate_count`, and for each one there will be `16 - rotate_count` possible values of `simple_length`. This can be described as a nested loop:

```
    for(rotate_count = 0; rotate_count < 16; rotate_count++) {
        for(simple_length = 0; simple_length = 16 - rotate_count; simple_length++) {
        }
    }
```

You can associate an "array of entries" with this, like:

```
    entry_number = 0;
    for(rotate_count = 0; rotate_count < 16; rotate_count++) {
        for(simple_length = 0; simple_length = 16 - rotate_count; simple_length++) {

            entry_number++;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use the entry number to find a hash table, like:

```
    entry_number = 0;
    for(rotate_count = 0; rotate_count < 16; rotate_count++) {
        for(simple_length = 0; simple_length = 16 - rotate_count; simple_length++) {
            hash_table = array_of_hash_tables[entry_number];

            entry_number++;
        }
    }
```

You can also rotate the string you're looking for by the `rotate_count` and extract `simple_length` characters from that, convert those characters into a hash, and use it to find a list of entries from the hash table, like:

```
    entry_number = 0;
    for(rotate_count = 0; rotate_count < 16; rotate_count++) {
        rotated_string = rotate_string(original_string, rotate_count);
        for(simple_length = 0; simple_length = 16 - rotate_count; simple_length++) {
            hash_table = array_of_hash_tables[entry_number];
            if(hash_table != NULL) {
                hash = get_simple_hash(rotated_string, simple_length);
                list = hash_table[hash];
                // Use "list" and "original string" to do the hard stuff here...
            }
            entry_number++;
        }
    }
```

This will quickly eliminate lots of entries (where the start and end don't match) and give you a list of "potential matches" where you'd have to check the part containing wild cards against the original string to determine if there is/isn't an actual match.

Note that if the characters are "ones and zeros" this can be improved by converting "strings containing binary digits" into integers.